# Search by date adds a day to the search

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to search for records by date ranges passing the dates from React but when they arrive in NodeJS they arrive with an extra day:

Mongoose Query:

```
search = { $or: [{createdAt:{$gte: startDate, $lt: endDate }}]};
```

I send the date like this from React:

```
console.log(startDate); // 2022-07-09T00:00:33.000Z
console.log(endDate); // 2022-07-09T00:00:33.000Z
```

But the server gets the date with one day too many:

```
start on server: 2022-07-10T00:13:58.901Z 
end on server; 2022-07-10T00:13:58.901Z
```

I don't understand how to solve it since I always get one more day and I can't find the real information anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Could you see what value is being passed in your network tab of chrome/Firefox?

Comment: Yes, start Sat, 09 Jul 2022 01:37:47 GMT

Comment: Could you share the code where you are making the request in react?